# Pressing a button from another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to call a function from another workbook which is a button(Actually I'm trying to click on it by macro).The workbook i'm trying to press a button function is protected by a password.So I've found name of the button by cracking password.

The workbook "SAP-SCHDULE v.0.1.xlsm" was open.
I have tried this way

```
Application.Run ("SAP-SCHEDULE v.0.1.xlsm!Sheet1(Parameters).CommandButton1_Click")
```

Workbook name : SAP-SCHEDULE v.0.1.xlsm

Worksheet name : Parameters

Button Name : CommandButton1

Despite all combinations of Application.Run(etc.) I couldnt manage to do it.

Thank you all.

Comment: `Sheet1(Parameters)` looks suspect.  Is it `Sheet1` or a sheet called `Parameters`?

Comment: Yes,It is sheet called Parameters.So the name of sheet  is Parameter.But in the project explorer it looks Sheet1(Parameters).

Comment: then its sheets("Paramaters") by using its name , or Sheets(1) by using its index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code should be

```
Application.Run "'SAP-SCHEDULE v.0.1.xlsm'!Sheet1.CommandButton1_Click"
```

That said, the SAP workbook may still not allow the code to run. If so, I think you are out of luck.